# EditText doesn't show keyboard on move

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an edittext which I am moving vertically when the user drags it with his finger. However I don't want that the keyboard opens when I lift the finger off the view after dragging.

How can I do this? Here is my code so far:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);               
            v.animate().y(event.getRawY() + dY).setDuration(0).start();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```